# Is it possible to solely use AWS S3 for nextcloud/opencloud drive

Tags: amazon-s3, owncloud, nextcloud

I'm trying to configure Nextcloud to use S3 as the sole path of all files and therefore not hold any files locally.

I guess this can be done but only within a subdirectory. Would it be possible to do it at the root path? It seems the External Storage configuration requires a folder to be entered and `/` does not seem to be valid.

Comment: Could you please supply some links to the technology you mention and some sample code? Also, you added an [owncloud] tag, but didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein `owncloud` and `nextcloud` are more or less synonyms currently, since fork and original have not yet diverged noticeably.

Comment: You certainly can mount the S3 bucket as the top level `files` folder in your local system using system tools. But you are right, this is _not_ possible by just using the configuration options owncloud or nextcloud offer.

Comment: This is directly supported.  [Relevant Nextcloud documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_files/primary_storage.html).

Comment: Note at the moment you must update config/config.php to reference your S3 object storage before the initial web install [reference](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/5865)